# SMTP not sending mail to new gmail account

Tags: wordpress, plugins, smtp

I am using WP Mail SMTP plugin right now. My problem is, I have 2 gmail accounts. First I had setup SMTP with gmail account number 1. It worked perfectly. Then I tried to setup SMTP with gmail account number 2.

Now here I am having problem. I am receiving mail in gmail account number 1. Since I had changed the setting I was expecting to receive mail in gmail account 2. I had also to check the option remove all the data from the misc and repeat the whole process from the scratch but still the same problem is occurring. And I had also deleted all the project from the console.developer from the of gmail account number 1.

Can anyone help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1)Make sure in your gmail account 2 'Gmail API' is enable for that go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/ and search for gmail api then enable it

2)If you are getting this error: EMAIL DELIVERY ERROR: WP Mail SMTP plugin logged this error during the last time it tried to send an email then check your gmail api is not exceeded.

3)You can refer this https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-send-email-in-wordpress-using-the-gmail-smtp-server/

Comment: thanks for the response. I have already tried one number but didn't work. And the real problem is i am not receiving any error. It is working perfectly but the not in the gmail account that i want.